# Cannot call function from within imported function

Tags: python, python-import

I have 2 files, the first is named function_call_test.py and contains the following code;

```
from Strategy_File import strategy

def function_1():
    print('This works')

strategy()
```

The second file is called Strategy_File.py and contains the following code;

```
def strategy():
    print('got here')
    function_1()
```

When running the first script I get 'NameError: name 'function_1' is not defined'.
I thought that when you imported a function that it was added to the importing modules namespace. If that is the case why can't strategy() see function_1()?

Just as importantly, how do I make this work. The above is for demo purposes only, I have reasons for wanting strategy() to be in a separate module.

Python 3.6, Windows 7-64, Visual Studio 2019 and IDLE

Comment: Is there really not a duplicate for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python is statically scoped. Lookup for a free variable (such as `function_1`) proceeds though the scopes where `strategy` is *defined*, not where it is called. As `strategy` is defined in the global scope of the module `Strategy_File`, that means looking for `Strategy_File.function_1`, and that function is not defined.

If you want `strategy` to call something in the *current* global scope, you need to define it to accept a callable argument, and pass the desired function when you call `strategy`.

```
# Strategy_File.py

# f is not a free variable here; it's a local variable
# initialized when strategy is called.
def strategy(f):
    print('got here')
    f()
```

and

```
# function_call_test.py

from Strategy_File import strategy


def function_1():
    print('This works')

# Assign f = function_1 in the body of strategy
strategy(function_1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to import every name into the file where it is used. So you need to modify `Strategy_File.py` to this:

```
from function_call_test import function_1

def strategy():
    print('got here')
    function_1()
```

But now you encounter a new problem: circular imports. Python won't allow this. So you will have to figure out a different way to organize your functions.

Comment: You’re right, but you haven’t actually answered the question have you. This is more like a comment.

Comment: @balmy The question answers how to fix the `NameError`. Someone else explains how to fix the circular import, so I'll leave it at that.

Answer (score 0):

This error caused by Strategy_File.py is missing definition of function_1().

<del>adding this line in Strategy_File.py on the top will helps.</del>

edit: circular imports will not help. sorry for the misinformation.

Comment: Python doesn't allow circular imports, so OP needs something like dependency injection to fix this.

Comment: While this solves the immediate error, it leads to another error.

Comment: Circular imports are fine, as long as you don't need a value defined in one module in order to define the other.

Comment: ah, you guys are right. Did pay attention that function 2 is called in the first file. edited. sorry for this misinformation.